# addition and subtract calculator

Tags: javascript, html

why is this not working. no error in console.

```
<html>
<head>
<Style>
#Input{ color: #3344ee
}

#h1 { font-face: comic-sans-ms;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="h1">INPUT YOUR NUMBERS</h1>



<input type="text" id="box1; input"  >+
<input type="text" id="box2" >
<input type="button" value="=" onclick='calsum()'>
<input type="text" id="result">
<hr>


<input type="text" id="box3" >-
<input type="text" id="box4" >
<input type="button" value="=" onclick='calsumsub)'>
<input type="text" id="resultsub" >

<script>
function calsum(){
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
let sum = Number(box1) + Number(box2);
document.getElementById("result").value = sum;
} 

function calsumsub(){
let box3 = document.getElementById("box3").value;
let box4 = document.getElementById("box4").value;
let sumsub = Number(box3)-Number(box4);
document.getElementById("resultsub").value = sumsub;
} 
</script>

</body> 


</html>
```

I don't know how to solve it.tried a lot. please don't give any down vote.checked a lot.
I am a learner. so may be something I forgot. thus please don't give any down vote.just be kind and help me. just ignore the css

Comment: There's just a ton of typos in there…!? `id="box1; input"`, `onclick='calsumsub)'`, and possibly more…

Comment: There are many great (and free!) online tools and validators you can use to catch these types of errors. There are also such tools built into (free!) IDEs. Using such tools can help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's a typo in box1 id `id="box1; input"`.

```html
<input type="text" id="box1"  >+
<input type="text" id="box2" >
<input type="button" value="=" onclick='calsum()'>
<input type="text" id="result">
<hr>


<input type="text" id="box3" >-
<input type="text" id="box4" >
<input type="button" value="=" onclick='calsumsub()'>
<input type="text" id="resultsub" >

<script>
function calsum(){
console.log("inside");
let box1 = document.getElementById("box1").value;
let box2 = document.getElementById("box2").value;
let sum = Number(box1) + Number(box2);
document.getElementById("result").value = sum;
} 

function calsumsub(){
let box3 = document.getElementById("box3").value;
let box4 = document.getElementById("box4").value;
let sumsub = Number(box3)-Number(box4);
document.getElementById("resultsub").value = sumsub;
} 
</script>

</body> 


</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir. got my mistakes. `thank you` I am a learner